# Need Python regex to extract last two words of URL

Tags: python, regex, url

Please, recommend regex expression to extract the last two words from an URL like:

```
    INPUT                             OUTPUT
'www.abcd.google.com'        -->   'google.com'
'www.xyz.stackoverflow.com'  -->   'stackoverflow.com'
```

Comment: Why regex? str.split() is easier in most cases

Comment: Thnx alot @jordanm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this regex with 'negative lookahead' feature:

```
import re
for url in ['www.abcd.google.com','www.xyz.stackoverflow.com']:
    print (re.search (r'\w*\.(?!\w*\.)\w*', url)[0])

google.com
stackoverflow.com
```

[Here is the example at Regexr](https://regexr.com/5bqhl):

Comment: Thnx a ton; exactly matches my regex reqmt...

Answer (score 1):

Use [`split`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) with `.` as delimetr:

```
url_strings = 'www.xyz.stackoverflow.com'

s = '.'.join(url_strings.split('.')[-2:])

# stackoverflow.com
print(s)
```

If input validation is required:

```
url_strings = 'www.xyz.stackoverflow.com'

def return_last_words(url_string, last_words_count=2):
    splitted = url_string.split('.')
    if last_words_count < len(splitted):
        return '.'.join(splitted[-last_words_count:])
    return url_string

print(return_last_words(url_strings))
```

Comment: thnx for an alternate to regex...

Comment: Welcome @Rubous please mark as solved :)